# Google Analytics Custom Variables not working

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

I am trying to log the username of users who are using my system.  Unfortunately, I couldn't track by using custom variables.  I could track the page visit, but custom variable tracking is not working.  Could you please help me?  Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxx-1']);
      _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
      _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'UserName','JohnPaul',2]);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);      

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();


    </script>
```

Comment: The code looks correct. You should be aware that logging usernames is forbidden on Google Analytics by the ToS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is correct and it does track the users now.  I just used the similar codes as above and it works now.  But I needed to wait 2 days to track the custom variables and it appears in my reports now.

Comment: do you have to write every username you want to track separated or how do you do it for more than one user

Comment: I am not sure.  But you might want to duplicate the Custom Variable tracking codes as the following.

_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'UserName','JohnPaul',2]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',2,'UserName','MarkSong',2]);

Answer (score 0):

For more than one user, you'll have to use PHP to output user names.

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'UserName', '<?php get_usernames(); ?>',2]);
```

***Substitute "get_usernames" with the function for your site that retrieves the usernames.